# phonegap android Build error . on windows

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, build

I'm getting this error when building my project. I have already set the PATH setting for android home, ant, java and ...

Any ideas whats the reason of this problem?

```
C:\helloworld>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
cp: no such file or directory: C:\helloworld\icon.png

Running command: C:\helloworld\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Work-PC\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
Running: C:\helloworld\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\helloworld\
platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:77)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:43)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:43)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

C:\helloworld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\helloworld\platforms\android\gradlew
  cdvBuildDebug -b C:\helloworld\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\helloworld\platforms\android\cord
ova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: C:\helloworld\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Work-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap
        \node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: It seems your Android SDK and tools are outdated. But you can also force it to build with ANT using ```cordova build android -- --ant```.